# Cloudera-Sqoop import with/without --hive-import

Tags: import, cloudera, sqoop

I'm trying to do an activity whereas i'll import a table from MSSQL then export to MSSQL again in another database for the sake of testing sqoop1. So far, my imports are successful. My concern is regarding the export, if i import a table **without** ***--hive-import*** option, i'll be able to export it successfully. But if i include ***--hive-import*** option, sqoop wont be able to export it and prompts an error:

> 17/04/02 23:08:20 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop:
>   org.kitesdk.data.DatasetIOException: Unable to load descriptor
>   file:hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/customer/.metadata/descriptor.properties
>   for dataset:customer org.kitesdk.data.DatasetIOException: Unable to
>   load descriptor
>   file:hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/customer/.metadata/descriptor.properties
>   for dataset:customer

As per checking, there's a difference in the metadata with --hive-imports. Imports with --hive-import parameter only does not have the required metadata:

```
Supplier/.metadata/descriptor.properties
```

My question is, is it possible to import a table in sqoop with --as-parquetfile and --hive-import option then be able to export it also?

here's my sample import and export code for referrence:

```
sqoop export \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.23;database=SqoopDB;schema=dbo;" \
--username sa \
--password Password1 \
--export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/customer \
--table customer

sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.23;database=SourceDB;schema=dbo" \
--username sa \
--password Password1 \
--table Customer \
--as-parquetfile \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \
-m 1
```